# how can i loop on tiptap text editor in vue.js 3 composition api

Tags: for-loop, vuejs3, text-editor, rich-text-editor, tiptap

im building a website for styling cv and resumes and im using tiptap text editor for building education section,Now i have one instance from the text editor and i want to loop on it to get several text editor in each education box

i just want on every click on add education button, a new education box reveals and new text editor for the new education box

but when i do that the text editor reveals only once ....please help me, any one help me :(

this website is similar to this website [www.jobseeker.com](http://www.jobseeker.com)   it's have the same functionality

here is the code

```
import { useEditor, EditorContent, Editor } from '@tiptap/vue-3'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'
import Underline from '@tiptap/extension-underline'
import TextAlign from '@tiptap/extension-text-align'
import Document from '@tiptap/extension-document'


const editor = new Editor({
    content: 'hfghfghfghfg',
    extensions: [
        StarterKit,
        Underline,
        Document,
        TextAlign.configure({
            types: ['heading', 'paragraph'],
        })
    ],
})
// the field property is what i loop on it 
const education = ref({
    inputText: "",
    menu: false,
    self: false,
    fields: [],
});
```

add buttons function:

```
const addingEduField = () => {
    education.value.fields.push({
        edu: "",
        school: "",
        city: "",
        startDate: { month: "", year: "" },
        endDate: { month: "", year: "", present: false },
        desc: '',
        key: true,
    });
};
```

this is the editor component which not looping :(

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in education.fields" :key="index">
  <editor-content :id="index" class="editor" :editor="editor" v-model="item.desc" />
<div/>
```

i tried to loop on the component and expected it will be more than one but actually it's become only one .........if someone has the same problem or have a solution please let me know it :(

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example from my code where I loop over blocks with content and I have a child component where I init each time a new editor for new content

```html
<div v-for="block of blocks" :key="block.uuid">
  <LessonEditorTipTap v-if="!isEmpty(block)" :content="block.content" />
</div>
```

inside `LessonEditorTipTap` component:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="editor">
    <EditorContent :editor="editor" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  props: {
    content: {
     type: Object,
     required: true,
     default: () => ({
      type: 'doc',
      content: [
       {
         type: 'paragraph',
       },
      ],
    }),
  },
},
data() {
  return {
    editor: null,
  };
},
mounted() {
  this.editor = new Editor({
    extensions: [
      Document,
      Paragraph,
      Text,
      Heading,
      Bold,
      Italic,
      Link,
      Dropcursor,
      Strike,
      HardBreak.configure({
        keepMarks: true,
      }),
      TextAlign.configure({
        types: ['heading', 'paragraph'],
      }),
      Gapcursor,
    ],
    content: this.content,
    onUpdate: () => {
      const newJSON = this.editor.getJSON();
      console.log('newJSON', newJSON);
    },
  });
}

</script>
```

sorry for the wrong indents, this is my first answer on StackOverflow